# Advanced data grid event handling

Tags: error-handling, advanceddatagrid

I have an advanced datagrid in my project. when i load it more than 2times i get the following error

TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at myComponents::GridCellFormatted/updateDisplayList()
 at mx.core::UIComponent/validateDisplayList()
 at spark.components::Group/validateDisplayList()
 at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateDisplayList()
 at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()
 at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()

When it loads fine the updatecomplete event is being fired . But when this error appears it doesnt seem to fire the update complete event. The only way i am able to see this error is because i have the debugger installed. Is there a an event i could use that catches any errors that occur when trying to load an advanced datagrid? Thank you.

Comment: Show us the code for GridCellFormatted. You have a bug in your updateDisplayList method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use initialize and have a handler that would have few trace statements to provide you with more information.

```
<s:AdvancedDataGrid id="adDataGrid" width="100%" height="100%" 
                                        initialize="adDataGrid_itemClickHandler(event)">

 protected function adDataGrid_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
 {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     trace(..);

 }
```